# Sorting by MAX value (HANA SQL)

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table A in HANA that looks like this:

```
Rank ID SOME_DATA1 SOME_DATA2 KEY SOME_REGION_DAT1 SOME_REGION_DAT2
8    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   1   xjxjxjxjxjxjx    jxjxjxjxjxjxjx
7    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   5   ababababababa    bababababababa
8    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   4   kikikikikikik    ikikikikikikik
5    2  albalbalb  hcuohcuo   7   hghghg
5    3  albalbalb  hcuohcuo   9   hghghg
4    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   2   kikikikikikik    ikikikikikikik
3    1  fffffffff  gggggggg   6   jkjjkjkjkjkjk    lalalalalalala
```

I'm wondering if there is anything I could use to get the result to look like this:

```
Rank ID SOME_DATA1 SOME_DATA2 KEY SOME_REGION_DAT1 SOME_REGION_DAT2
8    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   1   xjxjxjxjxjxjx    jxjxjxjxjxjxjx
8    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   4   kikikikikikik    ikikikikikikik
7    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   5   ababababababa    bababababababa
4    2  Blablabla  ouchouch   2   kikikikikikik    ikikikikikikik
5    3  albalbalb  hcuohcuo   7   hghghg
5    3  albalbalb  hcuohcuo   9   hghghg
3    1  fffffffff  gggggggg   6   jkjjkjkjkjkjk    lalalalalalala
```

It is like sorting by ID (to get kind of "blocks" by ID) and then within each "block" sort by RANK.

I have edited the question to see if I am lucky getting it easier to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a simple `order by`:

```
order by id, rank desc, key
```

EDIT:

I think you want:

```
order by max(rank) over (partition by id), id, key
```

Comment: I have tried that but the problem arises when I have an entry in TABLE A where the RANK and the KEY are the lowest values in the list. E.g. Rank = 1, Key = 0. In theory, because the RANK is the lowest value it should be at the end of the list but because we sort first by ID it is shown on the top

Comment: @400_BAD_REQUEST . . . Then your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I have made an enchilada over here... I have edited the question to see if people get it better.

Thanks for your patience

Comment: Hi Gordon. Your answer confirmed my "theory" that I was needing a window function... It works perfect !